# Trouble installing ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu on my desktop (currently running windows), but am getting stuck pretty early in the process.

Here's a recap of the steps I followed:

- download the ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso image
- create a bootable USB stick
- reboot, enter the boot selection menu, select the usb stick
- in grub (version 2.06), select "try or install ubunty"

I would expect to get ubuntu's installer to pop up, but instead I get:

- A quick flash (<1s) of "Error file/boot not found"
- grub appears and I can select "try or install ubunty"
- A few lines of "No irq handler for vector" warnings are printed
- After a few seconds, the uderscore "cursor" stops flashing and nothing more happens. I've left it for an hour, without any effect

Here's what I've tried to fix or troubleshoot the issue:

- checked the sha256sum of the iso file (it matches)
- used both balena etcher and rufus to create bootable media
- in rufus, used both ISO image mode and DD mode
- tried two different USB sticks
- tried both "try or install ubuntu" and "ubuntu with safe graphics"
  **note**: safe graphics produces a different output. [image: Ubuntu safe graphics error]
  at this point I'm in what looks like a limited bash prompt, where I can poke around a linux filesystem (cd, ls, cat, etc...), but I'm not sure what to do with it.
- I've seen a few people suggesting to do a memory check, but I can't see that option in grub, and I'd be surprised if the memory is faulty since windows is ok with it.
  [image: ubuntu grub]
- disabled fast boot in BIOS
- I can't figure out how to disable safe boot, I'd rather not do it, and I believe ubuntu can work with safe boot
  [image: BIOS safe boot menu]

Here is my config:

```
Device name [REDACTED]
Processor   AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor                3.59 GHz
Installed RAM   16,0 GB (15,9 GB usable)
Device ID   [REDACTED]
Product ID  [REDACTED]
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎28/‎01/‎2023
OS build    22621.2861
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22681.1000.0

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080
nvidia studio drivers v546.33
```

Answer (score 0):

1. NVIDIA RTX 3080 might cause issues with the standard Ubuntu installer due to driver compatibility. Using the “safe graphics” mode is a good step, but if that fails, you might need to use a minimal installation or a different version of Ubuntu (like an older LTS release) and then upgrade the system and drivers from there.
2. While you've mentioned that Windows runs fine, it's still worth running [a memory check](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-check-for-memory-problems-in-windows). You can use tools like [MemTest86 to create a bootable USB stick for memory testing](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/14201-memtest86-test-ram.html).
3. Try a Different USB Port. Sometimes, using a different USB port (preferably a USB 2.0 port instead of USB 3.0/3.1) can make a difference.
4. If none of the above works, consider creating a bootable DVD instead of a USB stick, if your system has an optical drive. I have come across cases where it was impossible to install Ubuntu via USB, there were completely different incomprehensible errors, I messed around all day and eventually installed using a DVD without a single error. I still don't understand what the problem was. So I suggest to try it if you have or can borrow a DVD drive.

**UPD, the answer to the comment:**

1. For compatibility with NVIDIA RTX 3080, I recommend starting with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
2. While the Windows Memory Diagnostic didn't find any issues, MemTest86 can sometimes detect problems that Windows diagnostics do not, due to its thorough and different testing approach. It's generally more detailed and can stress the memory more intensively. If you have the time, it might be worth running MemTest86 just to rule out any potential memory issues completely.
3. A USB DVD drive might behave differently from a USB stick due to the way some BIOS/UEFI firmware handles USB devices. It's less common nowadays, but if you can borrow an external USB DVD drive, it's worth a try.
4. Update BIOS/UEFI Firmware using Windows. Sometimes, updating the BIOS/UEFI firmware to the latest version can resolve compatibility issues with newer hardware and operating systems.
5. Ubuntu is compatible with Secure Boot, but sometimes it can cause issues. Temporarily disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS/UEFI settings might help. Ensure that the BIOS is set to UEFI mode, not Legacy or CSM, as Ubuntu prefers UEFI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

1. This sounds promising, but I don't know which release to choose. Would you recommend any specific one ?
2. I have run the windows memory diagnostic and it found no issues. Do you expect memtest86 to get a different result ?
3. I forgot to mention this in my question, but I did try multiple USB ports (USB 2 and 3). I've now also tried motherboard ports (not front panel), with the same result.
4. Unfortunately, I don't have an optical drive installed. Would a usb disk drive behave any differently from a usb stick ?

Comment: @bastiengirschig I updated the post, please read :-)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried ubuntu 20.4. I was able to get to the installer, choose my keyboard layout, etc... but now when I boot I either get stuck on the "startup screen" (with loads of green [ OK ] markers) or a black screen with a rapidly flashing cursor on the top left. I've waited 15 minutes each time, just in case, but nothing happened. One weird thing: I bought a separate disk to install ubuntu, and was very careful to select it while installing, but on the boot selection screen, both OSes seem to be on the same drive... However I cant see a new partition on that disk from windows.

Comment: @bastiengirschig Hi, is something worked out after all?

Comment: Unfortunately not. now, booting on the ubuntu drive just displays a flashing underscore at the top left of a fully black screen...